# Given a method in Ruby, is there a way to list all classes that respond to this method?

Tags: ruby, methods

For example, take the method 'each'. Is there a way to list all classes or their instances that respond to the 'each' method?

I don't mean to verify one by one if a class or its instance responds to the 'each' method. I ask if there is a way to list all classes at once.

Comment: It's been a while since I did anything in Ruby.  However, shouldn't you be able to click on the method in Rdoc and get all the classes that way?  If you wanted to do it programmatically you could probably look at the source code for Rdoc on github for inspiration

Comment: You mean something like `ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select {|c| c.public_method_defined?(:each) || c.respond_to?(:each) }.map(&:name).compact` in a fresh irb console I get `["Enumerator::Generator", "Enumerator::Lazy", "Enumerator", "ObjectSpace::WeakMap", "Process::Tms", "Dir", "File", "ARGF.class", "IO", "Range", "Struct", "Hash", "Array", "Gem::Specification", "IRB::DefaultEncodings", "Etc::Passwd", "Readline::History"]`

Comment: @engineersmnky That is the list of _currently loaded_ classes, that define method `name`.

Comment: This question basically can’t have a correct answer, because the set of classes is undefined. There is an ability to receive a list of all currently loaded classes, but it makes not much sense due to open classes paradigm of Ruby. I voted for closing the question as “too broad.”

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: @mudasobwa sorry I was not thinking about fictional Objects and if it's not loaded it's not real until it is loaded. If you asked for the number of animals with horns would you include or exclude a Unicorn or a jackalope? But I do agree there can't be a truly correct answer I was just thinking logically based on the question asked what result was the OP hoping for.

Comment: There's a fundamental difference between a class responding to `each` vs that class's instances responding to it. E.g. `Array` does not respond to `each`, but arrays do.

Comment: @engineersmnky I did not mean your answer is somehow incorrect, I just wanted to point out to corner cases :)

Comment: @Jordan I wasn't necessarily thinking of a particular problem. I was thinking how to override a method for all classes in which a particular method was defined - just out of curiosity.

Comment: @engineersmnky Interesting answer. Thank you.

Comment: @mudasobwa the question might be broad, but since I am new to programming I need to gradually understand some underlying aspects. You comment was important in that the list is restricted to loaded classes.